# Import "flask" could not be resolved Pylance

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, virtualenv, pylance

I am getting this missing import error.

[image]

I tried installing flask and flask alchemy again but it says requirement satisfied

Comment: Ctrl+P and then switch the "interpreter" to the correct virtual environment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you install the module?

You can do this by for example by writing `pip install flask` in your command line.

Comment: yes i have installed the module

Comment: So does it work now? As you accepted my answer.

Comment: If it does not work, you should check whether you are using the same python version in your VS Code as where you installed the module. You can use the command palette for this, and you can type p`python --version` where you typed `pip install flask`.

Comment: This is not a perfect way of doing it, but it should work. If it still does not work, find the location of both python version and see whether they are the same.

Comment: the problem was i didnt create venv for my flask app